# Scottish Higher Education Descriptor, What do these terms mean?

Tags: xml

http://docs.google.com/gview?a=v&q=cache:spO3YR6dNcoJ:www.sqa.org.uk/sqa/files/hn/F6C135.pdf

My class has just been discussing the course descriptor for the SQA Higher National Unit specification (Scottish higher education unit), We’ve been waiting for a response from the exam board for a few weeks and none has been forthcoming, perhaps you can make some sense of it.

> The candidate is required to produce of a well formed xml document. The XML document must follow the **document production label** and contain the following three parts:
>
> A XML document prologue…
>
> A root element…
>
> XML document must have only one root element…
>
> An optional miscellaneous section…

What is “the document production label” the only references to be found online are to the course descriptor. Any ideas?

“Metadata” and “attributes” are mentioned separately with no indication that these terms are being used synonymously, My educated guess is that these are being used as synonyms but any ideas?

> the XML document prologue must include **lactation** of an external validating schema

I’m assuming this is a typo for location, unless any of you have ever seen this used in a specific XML context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is ambiguity in the way that it is written.

I think they mean that the "Document Production Label" are these portions of an xml document.

1. A XML document prologue:

   - the XML processing instruction must contain the version, encoding and standalone
     attributes
   - the XML document prologue must include location of an external validating schema
   - the XML document prologue must contain an internal subset of declarations to augment or
     redefine declarations in the external validating schema.
2. A root element:

   - the root element is the XML element that contains all the other elements.
   - A well-formed XML document must have only one root element
3. An optional miscellaneous section:

   - the optional miscellaneous section may include XML comments, processing instructions,
     and white space

See this for single document explanation..

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XML_-_Managing_Data_Exchange/A_single_entity#Introduction

On the metaData and Attributes - that is very confusing as there is a different meaning to MetaData in xml world ...RDF?

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/06/rdf.html

Comment: Seems reasonable, the best we can tell is that by Metadata they mean an atribute being used to hold an item of data that isn't conceptually linked to the element, similar to the concept of a "artifical unique id" in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Might "document production label" be a mangled instruction on how to set the file name - somehow short for "document labeling/production guidelines"? It seems to be distinct from the instructions about the document content by the "and" which follows it.

`<joke>` XML document lactation is the foundation of the meta-dairy industry `</joke>`